# How do I include libraries in a ruby project?

Tags: ruby, ffmpeg, video-streaming, jruby

I installed `rvideo`.

```
gem install rvideo
aptitude install ffmpeg
```

I wrote the following using rvideo while reading a manual.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

file = RVideo::Inspector.new(:file => "/home/user/r/input.mp4")
file.fps        # => "29.97" 
file.duration   # => "00:40:23.4" 

transcoder = RVideo::Transcoder.new

recipe = "ffmpeg -i $input_file$ -ar 22050 -ab 64 -f flv -r 29.97 -s"
recipe += " $resolution$ -y $output_file$"
recipe += "\nflvtool2 -U $output_file$"
begin
transcoder.execute(recipe, {:input_file => "/home/user/r/input.mp4",
:output_file => "/home/user/r/output.flv", :resolution => "640x360"})
rescue TranscoderError => e
puts "Unable to transcode file: #{e.class} - #{e.message}"
end

transcoder.original     # RVideo::Inspector object
transcoder.processed    # RVideo::Inspector object
```

When I do:

```
$ ruby hw.rb
```

I get:

```
first.rb:3: uninitialized constant RVideo (NameError)
```

In the manual, I found this code:

```
require 'test/unit/assertions'
include Test::Unit::Assertions
puts assert_equal nil == nil, nil.nil?
```

How do I include rvideo library in my case? How do I know the path to the library?

Comment: You need to `require 'rvideo'` after the shebang.

Comment: `require': no such file to load -- rvideo (LoadError)`

Comment: You'll also need to `require 'rubygems'`

Comment: May you post the Ruby version you use? and if you use rvm (if yes: did you install the gem in the same gemset you use in the script?)?

Comment: @Hisako ruby 1.8.7 (2010-08-16 patchlevel 302) [x86_64-linux]

Comment: With 1.8.7, Anand's Answer should be correct.

Comment: @Hisako i was installing rvm and gem too was installed but they have disappeared. i done so `\curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --rails` and `source /usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm`

Comment: `rvm 1.17.7 (stable) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]`

Comment: if installed the jvm  then `su user` rvm disappeared. what?

Comment: jvm shouldn't be neccessary with MRI. also, never use "sudo" or the like when dealing with rvm or rubies or gems. (assuming you installed the user-wide version)

Comment: what do me fix? and How do me fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'rubygems'
require 'rvideo'

file = RVideo::Inspector.new(:file => "/home/user/r/input.mp4")
file.fps        # => "29.97" 
file.duration   # => "00:40:23.4" 

# rest of the code follows
```

Comment: is now set jvm and try again

Comment: `rescue in <main>': uninitialized constant TranscoderError (NameError)
        from first.rb:16:in `<main>'`

Comment: /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p362/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- transcodererror (LoadError)
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p362/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
        from first.rb:6:in `<main>'